# Excel Dynamic Chart Update Using Table

Tags: excel

I've read many posts on this site with similar issues of making a chart update dynamically.  I've tried the INDIRECT function as well as the built-in table approach, but still haven't gotten it to work.  I would greatly appreciate any clarification you can provide to help me with this.

My question is specifically the following:

I have a multi-sheet excel file.  The tab I'm working on looks like the following:

```
col. A     col. B    col. C    col. D    col. E    col. F
Fund Name: Fund1
Invstmnt1
Invstmnt2
Invstmnt3


Invst Date  Info1    Info2    Info3    Height    Baseline
```

Where I currently have the following formulas in the Invst column):

```
=VLOOKUP($A$2, 'Investment Data'!1:1000000,9,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP($A$3, 'Investment Data'!1:1000000,9,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP($A$4, 'Investment Data'!1:1000000,9,FALSE)
```

The following formulas in Info1 column:

```
=VLOOKUP($A$2, 'Investment Data'!1:1000000,3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP($A$3, 'Investment Data'!1:1000000,3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP($A$4, 'Investment Data'!1:1000000,3,FALSE)
```

Info 2 and Info3 have similar VLOOKUP's, just taking different columns from the Investment Data sheet.  The "Height" and "Baseline" columns simply help with the chart I built and are not relevant for my question here.

My question is the following: My sheet does what I want when the particular Fund input in cell B1, and the corresponding Investments associated with that Fund, are say 3 in number. I can make this sheet work if the number of Investments in a Fund was always the same.  The issue is that the number of Investments in a given fund varies from 1-20.  So in other words, I need to make this sheet flexible enough to work for 1 Investment, or 20.    After reading through SO posts, I created a table where "Invst", "Date", "Info1", "Info2", "Info3", "Height", and "Baseline" are my column headers, but I've been working on this for a few days now and I still can't get it to work dynamically as I would like it to.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide!  Thank you!

Just to clarify, the problem now is that if I repeat the VLOOKUP formulas for 20 rows, then when I have 3 Investments like in the example I provided, I get "#N/A" in all the rows without matching investments.  But if I don't put these 20 rows of VLOOKUPs, then if I have 20 investments, my chart does not include all the investments I want to include.

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, all you want is the `#N/A` to not show up once the `VLOOKUP` cannot find the investment?

Comment: Essentially yes. So if I could make 20 rows (the max. number of Investments) with VLOOKUP formulas, and only the rows where there is a corresponding Investment output values, the rest instead of "#N/A" would simply output nothing. That would be great.

Comment: To clarify, I use my cells as input for a chart, so I want the chart to show all the investments in a given fund, regardless of which fund I want to view

Comment: So what exactly is not happening correctly in the chart when the #N/A's appear?  If I remember correctly charts ignore errors

Comment: So the chart was including the #N/A's.  But actually your question made me add an If statement: =IF(A2="","",VLOOKUP...) and it seems like it might be working.  I'm just going to test out a longer investment example to see if it does.  Thanks for directing me in the right direction!!

Comment: Okay so it works for any number of investments.  Thanks!  The chart is a little goofy in that the baseline doesn't seem to adjust, so it has a lot of empty space if only 3 investments instead of 20, but that's not a serious issue, whereas the NA's previously made it too confusing to look at.

Comment: Glad you could come to a solution :) If that if statement worked you can also think about using something like `IFERROR(VLOOKUP,"")` that will also blank out all cases where the VLOOKUP didn't actually find the value, it all depends on your requirements though